# Android app crashes trying to open the site formerly known as Programmers

Tags: bug, android-app

I let Android submit the crash report several times since the site was renamed to Software Engineering.

The side drawer icon is labeled "Unknown Site programmers".

Are other people seeing this problem?

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X
- OS Version: 7.0 (3425233)

Comment: Aha. There is a workaround: Expand the list of favored sites then tap "Edit". "Unknown Site programmers" becomes "Software Engineering" and it no longer crashes.